# como crear una parabola en openGl o webGL

Tags: javascript, html5, opengl, webgl

Necesito dibujar la ecuación `y = 2x^2 - 1`, pero no encuentro cómo hacerlo, en el código ya se encuentran los JS de dibujar en la tarjeta de vídeo, etc. Me piden hacer esa ecuación modificando la función `draw`, cómo?

```
function draw(){
    init('gl_canvas', 'vertexShader', 'fragmentShader');
    if( gl ){
        var buffer;
        buffer = gl.createBuffer();
                       //x y  z
        var vertices = [0, 0 ,0 , -1 , -1 ,0 , 1 ,-1 ,0]; 

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer); 
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER , buffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer( program.aVertexPosition , 3 , gl.FLOAT , false , 0 , 0);

        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        G.deleteBuffer(buffer);          
    }
}
```

```js
var gl;
var program;

function setupShaders( vertexShaderName, fragmentShaderName ){

    // Setup Shaders:
    var v = document.getElementById(vertexShaderName).firstChild.nodeValue;
    var f = document.getElementById(fragmentShaderName).firstChild.nodeValue;

    var vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vs, v);
    gl.compileShader(vs);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vs));

    var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(fs, f);
    gl.compileShader(fs);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fs));

    program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, vs);
    gl.attachShader(program, fs);
    gl.linkProgram(program);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS))
        alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));

    // Setup Geometry:
    gl.useProgram(program);
    
    program.aVertexPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aVertexPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.aVertexPosition);
}

function init( canvasName, vertexShaderName, fragmentShaderName ){

    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasName);
    gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
    if(gl){

        setupShaders(vertexShaderName, fragmentShaderName);
    }

}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
         attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
         
         void main() {
             gl_Position  = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
             gl_PointSize = 10.0;
         }
      </script>
      <script id="fragmentShader"  type="x-shader/x-fragment">
         void main() {
             gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
         }
      </script>
      <script src="test.js" ></script>
      <script>
         function draw(){
         
             init('gl_canvas', 'vertexShader', 'fragmentShader');
             if( gl ){
         var buffer;
         buffer = gl.createBuffer();
                 //x y  z
         var vertices = [0, 0 ,0 , -1 , -1 ,0 , 1 ,-1 ,0]; 
         //q metodo esta activo
         gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer); //lo  q se haga de ahora en adelante es con ese buffer
         gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);//llenar el buffer en la memoria de video
           //32 bits por pixel , valores q no se cambian
           //float 0-255  
         
         gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
                 gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
         
         gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER , buffer);
         gl.vertexAttribPointer( program.aVertexPosition , 3 , gl.FLOAT , false , 0 , 0);//pasar vertice al vertexShader
              //cada vertice del arreglo tiene 3 coordenadas 
              //tipo flotantes 
              //escala falso
              //desde q indice del arreglo empieza a dibujar
              //espacios entre cada punto
         //coordenadas x y z = 3
         //gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 3);
         gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
         //dibujar puntos q son solo los vertices 
         // gl.TRIANGLES une los puntos y los rellena
         
         gl.deleteBuffer(buffer);    
         
         
         
                 
             }
         } 
         
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="draw();">
      <canvas id='gl_canvas' width="400" height="400"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Pues hay varias formas, la manera mas sencilla es cambiar tu tipo de primitiva a líneas o puntos, y simplemente generar las coordenadas de tu parabola y pasar esos datos como atributos del vertex shader, o también puedes utilizar un fragment shader manipulando el color de cada fragmento utilizando igual la formula de la prabola a cada fragmento.
El siguiente fragmento de código es para generar tus vertices:

```
var vertices = new Float32Array(14);

for (var i = 0; i <= 12; i+=2)
{
    var x = (i / 12) * 2 - 1; // coordenadas NDC
    vertices[i] = x;
    vertices[i + 1] = x * x;
}

var n = 7;
```

Y para dibujar solo cambias a la primitiva a líneas o puntos

Comment: las respuestas para que sean de calidad deben ser explicación mas código; de lo contrario se considera de baja calidad

Comment: por favor lee como responder https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Lei lo que dice tu enlace y no vi en ningún lado que deba agregar código, además veo mi respuesta clara y directa

Comment: Ahora esta directa por que agregaste código pero a como la tenías no era muy clara ni indicaba como proceder y no es mi enlace, es parte del tour de la propia página de SO en español